# Can't declare my property private using protocol oriented programming approach

Tags: swift

I am learning protocol oriented approaches and I am facing below issue when adding access modifiers.

I have an enum for mode type. It can be changed.

```
public enum ModeType: String {

    case Smart = "Smart"
    case Easy = "Easy"
}
```

I have created a protocol like below.

```
protocol Device {

    var deviceID: String { get }
    var title: String { get }
    var currentMode: ModeType { get set }
}
```

And below class conforms to the `Device` protocol.

```
class DeviceList: Device {

    public private(set) var currentMode: ModeType

    public private(set) var deviceID: String
    public private(set) var title: String

    init(deviceID: String, title: String, currentMode: ModeType, waterLevel: String, humidityLevel: String) {
        self.deviceID = deviceID
        self.title = title
        self.currentMode = currentMode
    }
}
```

Issue is `public private(set) var currentMode: ModeType`

but below works

`public internal(set) var currentMode: ModeType`

What am I misunderstanding here can anyone explain?

Comment: Well the protocol says that the `currentMode` property needs to be gettable and settable – your implementation says that it can't be settable outside the scope of the class. That's a clear contradiction.

Comment: @Hamish I need to change the value for (from out of scope) it so I need settable Right?

Comment: You need to make the setter of the property accessible at the scope in which both the protocol `Device` and class `DeviceList` are visible (i.e `internal`).

Comment: @Hamish Ok, I get that but still if I don't want to change it from out of scope and want to set with init only the why do I get an error for private(set). Sorry for asking as my concept for POP isn't clear.

Comment: Initialising the given property doesn't require it to be settable in the protocol requirement, so just remove `set` from the protocol requirement.

Comment: Ok, I got it Thanks @Hamish